# Java: Got warning "SimplifyBooleanExpression" .. how can I fix?

Tags: java, boolean

I got the warning that my expression could be easier.
Can you help me, how can I make it easier?

```
         ...
         for (int i = 2; i <= prims; i++) {
                if(isPrim(i)==true) {
                n.add(i);
            }
        }
        return n;
```

Comment: `if (isPrim(i))`

Answer (score 1):

Just reduce:

```
if (isPrim(i)) == true)
```

to:

```
if (isPrim(i))
```

XD